# Go to definition in web essentials

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, plugins, reference, web-essentials

I was trying to understand [web essential's **Go To Definition** feature statement](http://vswebessentials.com/features/javascript#definition):

> Go To Definition is built in to VS2012 and VS2013. This feature makes the feature work with `/// <reference>` constructs

- If the feature is built in with [VS](https://www.visualstudio.com/) what *different* this feature is doing?
- What is the reference construct in javascript?

According to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives), VS on itself can provide intellisense for outside .js files with the help of `Reference Directives`, so [what is the difference](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/136)?

Comment: VS Go To Definition works by itself works within a javascript files, not across a reference to another file. Web essentials extends this functionality.

Comment: The reference construct is documented, for example, here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Go To Definition by itself works within javascript files, not across a reference to another file (supposedly). Web essentials extends this functionality.

The reference construct is documented, for example, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb385682.aspx#ReferenceDirectives

As per [madskristensen](https://github.com/madskristensen)'s [comment](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials2015/issues/136#issuecomment-162964568)

> This is not for providing Intellisense, since VS supports that natively. It's for hitting F12 to Go to definition on one of those comments

Comment: So, web essential plugin will provide intellisense even if I don't have `/// <reference>` construct in my javascript file? This is too confusing.

Comment: Just updated this answer to clear the other doubt about VS's native intellisense support.